# Postgres Data Manipultion

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

so i have some data that look like this;

```
Column A  |  Column B
__________|__________
Chicken   |     2
Duck      |     8
Cat       |     3
```

How do i make it look like this?

```
  Column C  |
____________|
Chicken = 2 |
Duck = 8    |
Cat = 3     |
```

Answer (score 2):

try like below concatenate

```
SELECT clumnA || ' = '|| columnb AS ColumnC
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the concat function

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.4.1.1

`SELECT CONCAT("Column A", ' = ', "Column B") AS "Column C" FROM [table];`